# How to pass attributes to Vue.js component in vue router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

How to pass attributes to vuecomponent in vue router?

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/dashboard/profile",
        name: "DashboardProfile",
        component: <DashboardProfile foobar="false"/>, // <--- How can I achieve this?
    },
];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could pass a [prop object](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode) like :

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/dashboard/profile",
        name: "DashboardProfile",
        component: DashboardProfile,
        props:{show:false}
    },
];
```

then inside your component use that prop for conditional rendering at the component root.

Comment: I just want to know if it's even possible to pass attributes to the view component.

Comment: You couldn't do that in that way, you could not instantiate the component using `<></>`

Comment: could you provide a real code ? because that is not possible `<DashboardProfile foobar="false"/>`